# Accessing strings in an rc file

Tags: c#, string, embedded-resource

I have an rc file conating a string table that is in a dll say X.

I wish to use the strings in this string table in a C# project say Y present in the same solution. If the project Y was C++, I know you can use LoadString function, but for C#, I am not sure.

Can you list out the steps needed?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Yes, I am not even able to access the class in the dll from my C# project. I thought of creating a copy of the resource file in my C# project but that will cause maintenance problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `LoadString` thanks to P-Invoke

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint uID,StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);
```

Here also defintions of `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary`

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryA(string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

Comment: And why would you use P/invoke when there's a .NET method for it?

Comment: Theres a .NET method?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Which method? I only found how to load it from *managed* .NET assemblies. Not standard resources

Comment: You'd better document Load/FreeLibrary as well.

Comment: @addy2012 yes, so using the pinvoke functions, I can load the library, load the string and then free the library, just like how I do it in C++.

Comment: I am ok with using pinvoke but are there no C# functions to do the same? I read up on Load/Free library but they are all for C++

Comment: @TylerDurden .NET introduced another resource model. Its independent from the OS resource handling. That's why standard resources are not supported.